# Best path googleMaps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to create an application that identifies the best path for a person. But it would need to identify the importance of uphill and downhill on the way.

How getting this information of which path would be straight?

This app is for android. 
Tanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Elevation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/)

and [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)

The distance API may be the only thing you need.

Route information would be obtained by the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)

A combination between the 3 may be somewhat necessary, but once you setup an HttpClient to the google server you can just create back-end web service calls to grab the information you need on your android phone.